# MySQL my.cnf config setup for MyISAM

Tags: mysql, database

I currently have a Cloud based server with the following config.

```
CentOS 7 64-Bit
CPU:8 vCore
RAM:16 GB
MariaDB/MySQL 5.5.5
```

Unfortunately, I've inherited a MyISAM database and tables that I have no control to convert to INNODB even though the application performs many writes from many connections. The data is Wordpress Posts with the typical large text and photos.

I'm experimenting with my.cnf config changes and was wondering if the config I've developed here is making use of the resources in the most effecient way.  Is there anything glaring I could increase/decrease to squeak out more performance?

```
key_buffer_size=4G
thread_cache_size = 128
bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
join_buffer_size=64M
max_allowed_packet=128M
query_cache_limit=128M
read_buffer_size=16M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
sort_buffer_size=16M
table_cache=128
tmp_table_size=128M
```

Answer (score 0):

This will depend entirely on the type of data you are storing, the structure and size of your tables and the type of usage your database has. Not to mention the amount of available RAM and the type of disks your server has.

The best recommendation, if you have shell access to the server (which I assume you must, otherwise you couldn't change my.cnf) is to download the [mysqltuner script from major.io](https://major.io/mysqltuner/)

Run this script as a user with privileges to access your database, and preferably with root privileges on mysql too (the ideal is to run it under sudo or root) and it will analyse your database access since mysql's last restart, and then give you recommendations to change the options in my.cnf

It isn't perfect, but it'll get you much further, and more quickly, than anyone on here trying guess what values would be appropriate for your use case.

And, while not trying to pre-empt the results, I wouldn't be surprised if mysqltuner recommends that you drastically increase the size of your join buffer, table_cache and query_cache_limit.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I will check it out.  RAM is currently 16GB and the data is Wordpress Posts with the typical large text and photos using serialized data.